# Having trouble producing transparent GIF animation

Tags: graphics, export, animation, gif-format

I'm having difficulty producing a proper animated gif (for inclusion in a PowerPoint presentation). The code I have is this:

```
 HSBhsl[h_, s_, l_] := 
 Module[{H, S, B}, H = h; B = l + s (1 - Abs[2 l - 1])/2; 
  S = (2 B - l)/B; {H, S, B}]
TestCube[\[Theta]_] := 
 Graphics3D[Rotate[{EdgeForm[], Hue[HSBhsl[32/250, 228/250, 105/256]],                  
    Cuboid[{0, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 1}]}, -\[Theta] Degree, {0, 0, 1}, {1, 1,
     1}], Lighting -> {{"Ambient", 
     RGBColor[0.7, 0.7, 0.7]}, {"Directional", 
     RGBColor[0.35, 0.35, 0.35], ImageScaled[{0, 5, 0}]}}, 
  Boxed -> False, Background -> None, 
  PlotRange -> 4 {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}, ViewAngle -> Pi/10000]
```

The animation is then produced like so:

```
list = Table[
   Show[TestCube[t], ViewPoint -> {1000, 1000, 1000}], {t, 0, 360, 1}];
SetDirectory@NotebookDirectory[];
Export["CubesAnimation.gif", list, "TransparentColor" -> White]
```

Unfortunately, this produces an amimation that seems to stack images on top of each other, thus giving the appearance of a "trace" left by the previous frame. I tried adding `"TransitionEffect" -> Background`, but this had no effect.

How do I get a proper GIF animation, with a transparent background, of the rotating cube?

Comment: You haven't defined HSBhsl

Comment: Sorry, updated my post. Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "proper"?  Just using `Export["CubesAnimation.gif", list]` seems to produce a "proper" GIF.

Comment: The issue is that this results in the animation having a white background. I need the background to be transparent. Using the options I gave in my post, I do get a transparent background, but I also get that unwanted "stacking effect".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have investigated the problem and it seems that this is indeed a limitation of `Export`. We will add support for `"TransitionEffect"` option in `Export` in the next release of Mathematica.

In the meantime, as a workaround, you can use a low-level function from GIFTools paclet `` GIFTools`Private`$WriteFrames ``. The function is not documented because it is not supposed to be used directly, it serves as a back-end to `Export`.

But here is how you can use it in your case:

```
list = Table[Show[TestCube[t], ViewPoint -> {1000, 1000, 1000}], {t, 0, 360, 1}];
SetDirectory@NotebookDirectory[];

(* Load and initialize GIFTools paclet *)
Needs["GIFTools`"]
GIFTools`Private`InitGIFTools[]

GIFTools`Private`$WriteFrames[
    Image3D[list],           (* All frames stuffed into a single Image3D *)
    "CubesAnimation.gif",    (* Output file name *)
    "",                      (* Comment, none in this case *)
    {0.1},                   (* Display duration for each frame *)
    "None",                  (* Dithering method, none in this case *)
    1,                       (* How many times to play the animation *)
    True,                    (* Interlacing *)
    {255, 255, 255},         (* Background color *)
    {255, 255, 255},         (* Transparent color - white *)
    {2}                      (* Disposal mode - Restore to background color*)
]
```

As an alternative you can consider exporting to Animated PNG, which supports alpha channel.

Comment: How nice! But, is the semicolon in `Image3D[list];` deliberate?

Comment: No, it was a typo, I have edited my answer. Thanks for catching that.

Comment: Thanks, this solves the issue!

Comment: Unfortunately, Powerpoint doesn't seem to support animated PNGs.

Comment: …and the animated PNG that is produced doesn't seem to have transparency, either.

Comment: @Pirx, "This seems to work, but I can't find my output file" - just as a check, did you try searching for the file you just created in the other `*Directory` locations known to *Mathematica*?

Comment: @Pirx, Hmm, that should be loaded when you first try to export an image as a GIF. Try running `ExportString[Image[{{1}}], "GIF"]` first, and then ``GIFTools`Private`InitGIFTools[]``. The last one should return `True` if it got loaded.

Comment: Hah, I got it now: It was some issue with cut-and-paste mangling that backwards quote; I did get a character that looks like a backwards quote, but apparently it wasn't the right backward quote. Just manually typing that quote in Mathematica fixed the issue. Thanks everybody!

Comment: One final question on this: Can I set the output resolution of the GIF in GIFTools?

Comment: To set the output resolution you should use `ImageSize` option of `Image`: `list = Table[Image[Show[TestCube[t], ViewPoint -> {1000, 1000, 1000}], ImageSize -> 200], {t, 0, 360, 1}];`

Comment: @Pirx, if you want to control resolution, feed the stuff in `list` to `Rasterize[]` first.

Comment: Quick update on this issue of loading GIFTools: Something seems to be wrong here, and it is not related to those backwards quotes (which turned out to be fine). The paclet simply does not load if I just try to run the code as is. However, if I insert the command `ExportString[Image[{{1}}], "GIF"]` first, then things work fine. I guess I'm not sure I understand the paclet loading mechanism/logic here. Oh well.

Comment: @Pirx, you're right, sorry, I have added GIFTools initalization code to my answer.

Comment: Thanks very much!

Answer (score 4):

To export to an animated PNG with transparency you should convert `Graphics` to `Image` first:

```
list = Table[Image[Show[TestCube[t], ViewPoint -> {1000, 1000, 1000}]], {t,
       0, 360, 1}];
```

Then, you call `Export`:

```
In[9]:= Export["CubesAnimation.png", list]

Out[9]= "CubesAnimation.png"

In[10]:= ImageMeasurements[Import["CubesAnimation.png", {"ImageList", 1}], "Transparency"]

Out[10]= True
```